# Salvar estado de função em Haskell

Tags: haskell

Quero implementar um botão que sempre que for clicado mude de estado em haskell.
Se ele estiver ligado quando apertar ele deve desligar e vice versa.

Em c++ eu salvaria o estado em uma variável global, mas em haskell não faço ideia!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haskell é uma linguagem puramente funcional. É impossível salvar o estado de alguma coisa. A única forma de conseguir o que você quer é passar para uma função duas coisas ao mesmo tempo: o estado anterior do botão e a ação do usuário. A função então deve decidir o novo estado do botão dependendo da ação.

Um exemplo simples:

```
-- Novo tipo para representar o botão
data Botao = Ligado | Desligado deriving (Eq, Show)

-- Novo tipo para representar uma acao
data Acao = Pressiona | Nada deriving (Eq, Show)

-- Recebe o estado de um botao, mais uma ação e retorna um novo estado
runBotao :: Botao -> Acao -> Botao 
runBotao Ligado    Pressiona = Desligado -- Se ligado e pressionado, muda para desligado
runBotao Desligado Pressiona = Ligado    -- Se desligado e pressionado, muda para ligado
runBotao s         Nada      = s         -- Se não houver ação, permanece no estado original
```

Você pode testar no GHCi, por exemplo:

```
ghci> Ligado `runBotao` Nada `runBotao` Pressiona `runBotao` Pressiona
Ligado
```

Neste exemplo, um botão começa `Ligado`, depois não há ação, depois é pressionado e por fim é pressionado de novo.

Para trabalhar com estados de forma mais aprofundada e mais generalizada, recomendo que leia sobre a [mônada `State`](http://haskell.tailorfontela.com.br/for-a-few-monads-more#state) (infelizmente parece que esse capítulo ainda não foi traduzido para o português).